# if condition for sting get from entry to compare with given string

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new in python
I wanted to make a program that when you write a specific string in entry it compares it with a string and get an output but it doesnt go well ,where is the mistake i have done?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
app=Tk()

load = Entry(app, width=10)
loadvar = StringVar

z = loadvar.get()

if  z == "winner"
    Label(app,text="congrats",).grid(row=1,column=0)
    
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: You're not waiting for the user to type something in the entry.

Comment: Try puting the entire code inside '''. Anyway, it seens like you are missing : in the end of if sentense, and the rest should be indent under if.

Comment: See [here](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-stringvar/) for a tutorial on using StringVar. You have several basic problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

app = Tk()

# Entry
loadvar = StringVar()
load = Entry(app, width=10, textvariable=loadvar)
load.grid(row=0, column=0)
load.focus()


def compare():
    if loadvar.get() == "winner":
        # Label
        Label(app, text="congrats", ).grid(row=1, column=0)


# Button
Button(text="Compare", command=compare).grid(row=0, column=1)

app.mainloop()
```

In your code, you have not placed the Entry widget yet. Moreover, you should use Buttons and link them with the function you want so that you can carry it out each time you are using it. Otherwise, you are check if the text inside entry is equal to 'winner' even before typing into it.

```
loadvar = StringVar
```

This line must be before creating Entry and then put in "textvariable" attribute of the widget.